# Android: Facebook API 4.6, can I make the call back manager singleton?

Tags: java, android, facebook

Hi I am reading the documentation and I am confused with the use of the CallbackManager class and what it is used for.

My app is basically a single activity and everything else is a fragment

But what confused me in the documentation is this

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

So in the example callbackManager is a member of some activity class but (Going beyond my use case) what if you had many activities? Would you still call on each activity having a member callbackManger

```
 callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
```

Anyway, it is ok if the call back was created in the Application instance?

```
      public class MainApplication extends Application {

      private CallbackManager callbackManager;
      private MainApplication instance;


        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            instance = this;
            FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
            callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

       }
    }
```

And then using the relevant getters and setters

Please help
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CallbackManager should be created for each activity (or fragment) that actually uses the Facebook features (like Login or Share). You should not put it in the Application class because it does keep some state that's specific the the activities (or fragment).